# Cannot append html in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Trying to make loader for project on backbone and underscore.

In view make

```
var loader = new Loader(); loader.start();
```

But in Loader, image not append.

```
this.$el.append('<div class="loader"><img src="i/preloader.gif"></div>');
```

.

```
console.log(this.$el);
0: div#block.blockcontext: documentlength: 1selector: "#block"__proto__: Object[0]
```

If I add in loader:

```
$('.block').append('<div class="loader"><img src="i/preloader.gif"></div>');
```

It not will append it, but if I made this in browser console - it work.

**Whats wrong, any idea?**

---

**Filename: loader.js**

```
define([
    'backbone'
], function(Backbone) {

    "use strict";

    var Loader = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $("#block"),

        initialize: function() {
            this.render();
        },

        start: function() {

            this.parentPosition = this.$el.css('position');

            if (this.$(".loader").length == 0) {
                this.$el.append('<div class="loader"><img src="i/preloader.gif"></div>');
            }

            this.$(".loader").css({opacity: 1}).show();
            this.$el.css({position: 'relative'});

            this.el.scrollTop = 0;
        },

        stop: function() {
            var _this = this;

            this.$(".loader").animate({opacity: 0}, 100, 'linear', function() {
                _this.$el.css({position: _this.parentPosition});
                $(this).css({display: "none"});
            });
        }
    });

    return Loader;
});
```

**Filename: view.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'router',
    'model/model',
    'loader'
], function($, _, Backbone, Router, appState, Loader) {

    var Block = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#block"),

        templates: {
            "selected_currency": _.template($('#step_1').html())
        },

        initialize: function() {
            this.model.bind('change', this.render, this);

            var loader = new Loader();
            loader.start();
        },

        render: function() {
            var state = this.model.get("state");
            $(this.el).html(this.templates[state](this.model.toJSON()));
            return this;
        }
    });

    new Block({model: appState});
});
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/general.css">

        <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <table class="main-container" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="block" class="block"></div>

                        <script type="text/template" id="step_1">
                            <div class="line step">

                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="td_right">Currencies:</td>
                                        <td>
                                            <select class="chosen-select select" name="currency" required>
                                                <% _.each(currencies, function(currency){ %>
                                                    <option value="<%= currency %>"><%= currency %></option>
                                                <% }); %>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <br>
                                            <button type='submit' class='btn btn-success'>Next</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                        </script>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Filename: main.js**

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        jquery: 'lib/jquery-2.1.1',
        underscore: 'lib/underscore',
        backbone: 'lib/backbone',
        view: 'view/view'
    },

    shim: {
        'backbone': {
            deps: ['jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    }
});

require([
    'app'
], function(App) {

    App.initialize();
});
```

Comment: Make sure view is attached to DOM element.

Comment: I look at your murkup and do not see where is the main script.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `el:` definition is wrong.

Should be just `el: #block`

Comment: $('.block').append('<div class="loader"><img src="i/preloader.gif"></div>'); Even this not work in my loader =(

Comment: How better to fix it? $(function(){ ... }); Can't help i nthis case.